# Context initialization failed java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/hazelcast/core/HazelcastInstance

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, hazelcast

I am trying to create a spring MVC application. I have a parent pom, a common project for models, a channel project which contains all controller and a business logic project. 
Apart from channel project, both are jar and are included as dependencies in channel project. Now Whenever I am trying to start my server it's looking for hazelcast dependency however I am not using hazel cast at all in my

Project specifications
Spring 4.3.12.RELEASE
STS : 3.9.1
Java JDK 1.8.61

Server : Apache Tomcat 9
         Pivotal server 3.0-3.2

web.xml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>spring-global-common-channels</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <!-- needed for ContextLoaderListener -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:group/sk/common/resources/spring-application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Bootstraps the root web application context before servlet initialization -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- The front controller of this Spring Web application, responsible for 
        handling all application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:group/sk/common/resources/spring-application-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map all requests to the DispatcherServlet for handling -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-application-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.3.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="*"></context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:cors>
        <mvc:mapping path="*localhost:8080*" />
    </mvc:cors>

</beans>
```

Error Trace :

---

> 2018-02-11 11:57:04,215  INFO [main] DefaultListableBeanFactory:828 -
>   Overriding bean definition for bean 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector'
>   with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector];
>   scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=true; autowireMode=0;
>   dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
>   factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null;
>   destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=;
>   abstract=false; lazyInit=true; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0;
>   autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
>   factoryBeanName=delegatingWebMvcConfiguration;
>   factoryMethodName=mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector; initMethodName=null;
>   destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration]
>   2018-02-11 11:57:04,297 ERROR [main] ContextLoader:355 - Context
>   initialization failed  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/hazelcast/core/HazelcastInstance  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)   at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:570)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:697)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:640)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1484)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:425)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4643)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5105)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:671)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493) Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance  at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1275)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1104)
>     ... 49 more 2018-02-11 11:57:04,318  INFO [main]
>   XmlWebApplicationContext:984 - Closing Root WebApplicationContext:
>   startup date [Sun Feb 11 11:56:45 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
>   2018-02-11 11:57:04,328  WARN [main] XmlWebApplicationContext:1002 -
>   Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close 
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized -
>   call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root
>   WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Feb 11 11:56:45 IST 2018];
>   root of context hierarchy     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:427)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:999)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:583)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4690)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5327)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:671)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
>   2018-02-11 11:57:04,329 DEBUG [main] DefaultListableBeanFactory:512 -
>   Destroying singletons in
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7fef2b7a:
>   defining beans
>   [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory,channelCtrlServiceImpl,proxyAsyncConfiguration,schedulingConfiguration,MBeanExportConfiguration,loadTimeWeavingConfiguration,proxyCachingConfiguration,hibernateConfig,springHttpSessionConfiguration,jdbcHttpSessionConfiguration,gemFireHttpSessionConfiguration,mongoHttpSessionConfiguration,redisHttpSessionConfiguration,hazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration,proxyTransactionManagementConfiguration,delegatingWebMvcConfiguration,mvcContentNegotiationManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping,mvcCorsConfigurations,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter,mvcUriComponentsContributor,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionalEventListenerFactory,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor,mbeanExporter,loadTimeWeaver,org.springframework.cache.config.internalCacheAdvisor,cacheOperationSource,cacheInterceptor,sessionEventHttpSessionListenerAdapter,springSessionRepositoryFilter,springSessionJdbcOperations,sessionRepository,propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer,sessionRegionTemplate,ClusteredSpringSessions,sessionRegionAttributes,principalNameIndex,sessionAttributesIndex,mongoSessionRepository,redisMessageListenerContainer,sessionRedisTemplate,enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer,transactionAttributeSource,transactionInterceptor,requestMappingHandlerMapping,mvcPathMatcher,mvcUrlPathHelper,viewControllerHandlerMapping,beanNameHandlerMapping,resourceHandlerMapping,mvcResourceUrlProvider,defaultServletHandlerMapping,requestMappingHandlerAdapter,mvcConversionService,mvcValidator,httpRequestHandlerAdapter,simpleControllerHandlerAdapter,handlerExceptionResolver,mvcViewResolver];
>   root of factory hierarchy

Parent Pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sk.springboot.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-global-common-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>spring-global-common-parent</name>
    <description>spring-global-common-parent</description>
    <properties>
        <spring.framework.version>4.3.12.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jackson.version>2.9.3</jackson.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.12.Final</hibernate.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: tomcat/web runtime is missing the "hazelcast" dependencies...

Comment: is it required by tomcat??

Comment: no: or it is something of your code (which is not shown yet/here) ...or it is a (spring) version clash

Comment: hazelacst: "The Leading Open Source In-Memory Data Grid" ...

Comment: @xerx593 : There is nothing in code yet just a controller which does nothing just send a string of "Response from" + className

Comment: "something" tries to define/initialize `hazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration` (bean)

Comment: plz, show also the pom/dependencies of "channel" project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Session will use Hazelcast.
See https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/java-hazelcast.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Stevenson. I also tried the same by removing those dependencies which i was having doubt upon. Now I am trying to resolve for ` java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/hateoas/mvc/UriComponentsContributor.` and it seems to be coming due to spring data. I need to sync up my dependencies for resolution

Comment: If you're just starting to develop this app, you'll find Spring Boot the easiest to get going, and you can then extend out with other bits as you need them.